# short-circuiting behavior of conditional OR operator(||)

Tags: java, operators

Both conditional operators && and || are short-circuited as per
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html, which means the second operand does not need to be evaluated at times.

**Could somebody please provide an example in which the conditional-OR(||) operator would be short-circuited?**

Short-circuiting behavior is pretty straightforward with the conditional-AND(&&) operator as in:

if(false && (1 > 0)) then the second operand:(1 >0) would not need to be evaluated but can't seem to find/think of an example for conditional-OR.

Comment: Short circuiting will happen when the result of the first operand can define the outcome of the logical operation. For `&&` the first becoming `false` will make the result `false` definitely and for `||` the first becoming true will make the result `true` definitely. So the first operand being `true` will short circuit always for the `||` operator.

Comment: Why is it less straightforward with ||? It is exactly as straightforward as with &&. The computation of expressions is stopped when the value of the entire condition is known. Expressions are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: @MichaelSchmeißer: sorry don't know how I missed it being straightforward.

Answer (score 22):

The or operator is short-circuited when the first operand is true.  So,

```
String foo = null;
if (true || foo.equals("")) {
    // ...
}
```

doesn't throw a `NullPointerException`.

As @prajeesh rightly points out in the comments, on way that short-circuiting is used in real code is to prevent a `NullPointerException` whenever you are dealing with an API that might return null.  So, for instance, if there is a `readStringFromConsole` method that returns either the currently available string or null if the user doesn't type anything, we could write

```
String username = readStringFromConsole();
while (username == null || username.length() == 0) {
    // No NullPointerException on the while clause because the length() call
    // will only be made if username is not null

    System.out.println("Please enter a non-blank name");
    username = readStringFromConsole();
}

// Now do something useful with username, which is non-null and of nonzero length
```

As a side note, an API that returns user input should return the empty string whenever the user doesn't type anything, and shouldn't return null.  Returning null is a way of saying "there is nothing available," while returning the empty string is a way of saying "the user didn't type anything" and so is preferred.

Comment: I didnt get a situation where this specific `true || foo.equals("")` makes things look sensibly logical, it should be `if(foo==null || foo.equals(""))` which will short circut when `foo` is null and thus prevent the NPE.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(true || (0 > 1))
```

The first statement is true, and so it is not necessary to evaluate the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (true || comparison)
```

comparison will never be evaluated, since its result is irrelevant (because the first argument is already true).